# Ubuntu 16.04 making requests to search.apps.ubuntu.com

Tags: 16.04, services

My firewall is showing intermittent https requests to 162.213.33.200 (search.apps.ubuntu.com) from my Ubuntu 16.04 server.  What is making these requests and how do I shut it down?

Comment: try with netstat / `ss -tulpen` output you'll be able to see which process is attempting connection. then disable it. seems like ubuntu application upgrade sort of program

Comment: @v_sukt that didn't help I ran it at the same time I was seeing the requests but the "Foreign Address" column in the output is all 0.0.0.0:* so it is not helpful and looking at the list of programs is not helpful at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out it is being generated by snapd https://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/snappy, don't know how to disable the periodic requests it is making so I ended up just disabling that service (snapd.service) as I'm not using any snaps.

If in the future someone figures out how to disable the periodic requests it is  making please feel free to post it here.